# Como capturar o id de cada linha de uma lista com o scroll?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista com 200 linhas, e cada linha tem o seu id.

Gostaria de capturar com o javascript, o id de cada linha ao descer a página.

A lista está montada deste jeito:

```
<ol id="noticias">
    <li id="geral" class="area">
      Conteudo
    </li>
    <li id="esportes" class="area">
      Conteudo
    </li>
    <li id="mundial" class="area">
      Conteudo
    </li>
    <li id="tecnologia" class="area">
      Conteudo
    </li>
</ol>
```

Tentando explicar de outra forma.

Eu montei uma array, na qual, cada entrada representa uma linha da minha lista.
Em cada entrada existem dois campos, um com a altura da linha e outro com o id da linha.

Está assim:

var listas = [
    [45,'noticias'],
    [50,'tecnologia'],
    [100, 'mundo']
];

A cada scroll que desse na página, o programa captura a altura do body, e com o valor da altura do body, ele analisa em qual campo estou no array

Solução:

Eu consegui utilizando esta função:

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {

    var altura_body = $(window).scrollTop();

    for (var i = 0; i <= numero_de_linhas; i++) {
        if (altura_body >= listas[i][0] && altura_body <= listas[i + 1][0]) {
            $(".mostra_id").html(listas[i][1]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Como é o HTML dessa lista? Não precisa colocar as 200.

Comment: eu capturei as alturas das linhas e os id's em um array array_altura_linhas, daí usando o $(window).on("scroll resize", function() {}, eu gostaria de comparar a altura do "body" com a array_altura_linha e saber em qual index ele se encaixa

Comment: As ids eu já capturei e estão numa array, cada membro da array tem dois campos, um com a altura da linha e outro com o id

Comment: Então gostaria com o scroll, ver a altura do body (já fiz isso, numa variável altura_body), com esse valor do altura_body ele deveria fazer uma varredura nessa array no campo das alturas das linhas, e achar em qual index ele está

Comment: Eu quero que o id da lista que está na tela apareça numa div e mude confforme eu for descendo a página

Comment: Eu reescrevi a pergunta, veja se consegui deixar mais claro

Comment: Aparece apenas o nome do id que está na tela, sabe? Quando desço a paina e chego no campo de "tecnologia", aparece no campo que estou na linha de "tecnologia"

Comment: isso! Explicando de outro jeito: Eu tenho uma variável x = 55, como comparar com esse array var listas = [ [45,'noticias'], [50,'tecnologia'], [100, 'mundo'] ]; e ver em qual index ele se encaixa

Comment: Com essa construção de array é complicado. Poderia fazer um objeto.

Comment: Precisa editar a pergunta e explicar tudo direitinho. Tá mt confuso. O código eu tenho pronto. As ids vão aparecendo no console à medida que os itens da lista vão aparecendo, mas tb aparecem as ids das que já estão visíveis.

Comment: Obrigado cara, vou tentar reescrever para ver se fica mais claro, mas, valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz desta forma com JS puro, já que não foi marcado a tag jQuery (explicações no código):

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   var lista = document.querySelectorAll("#noticias li");
   for(var x=0; x<lista.length; x++){
      var elTopo = lista[x].offsetTop; // distância relativa do elemento ao topo
      var scrlTopo = window.pageYOffset; // scroll da janela
      var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela
      var distance = elTopo-scrlTopo; // distância absoluta do elemento ao topo
      if(distance <= altJanela){ // verifico se o elemento apareceu na janela
         document.querySelector(".mostra_id").innerHTML = lista[x].id;
      }else if(lista[0].offsetTop-scrlTopo >= altJanela){ // se o primeiro elemento da lista sumir
         document.querySelector(".mostra_id").innerHTML = ''; // apaga o conteúdo da div
      }
   }
});
```

```css
.mostra_id{
   position: fixed;
   top: 30px;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mostra_id"></div>
Role a tela
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<ol id="noticias">
    <li id="geral" class="area">
      geral
    </li>
    <li id="esportes" class="area">
      esportes
    </li>
    <li id="mundial" class="area">
      mundial
    </li>
    <li id="tecnologia" class="area">
      tecnologia
    </li>
</ol>
```